# Uncaught TypeError: content[contentType] is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jsx, vite

my goal is if i pass props like so : `modalService.getContent('my_element1', {someProp: 'someProp'})` then my content should return `***COMPONENT 1***`

I looked into Render Props in React Docs but didn't find the answer I was looking for, anyone know how to find a work around for this?

```js
const TesterElement1 = () => {
  return <div>***COMPONENT 1***</div>;
};

const TesterElement2 = () => {
  return <div>***COMPONENT 2***</div>;
};

const TesterElement3 = () => {
  return <div>***COMPONENT 3***</div>;
};

export class ModalService {
  getContent(contentType, prop) {
    const content = {
      my_element1: (props) => <TesterElement1 info={props} />,
      my_element2: (props) => <TesterElement2 info={props} />,
      my_element3: (props) => <TesterElement3 info={props} />,
    };
    return content[contentType](prop);
  }
}
```

I am trying to render a specific element in a different component based off the properties given to ModalService like so:

```
const myNewElement = ({ type, prop }) => {
  const modalService = new ModalService();
  const content = modalService.getContent(type, prop); 
  
  return (
    {content}
  )
}
```

if I run the snippet i get this error: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"`
if I look at console i get this error: `"Uncaught TypeError: content[contentType] is not a function"`
and when I check my sandbox in replit its working as intended.

I am reusing old code that was built using webpack and trying to rebuild it from scratch with Vite 4. I am wondering if that is why its not working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

managed to get rid of the error and found a temporary solution. In this declaration `const content = modalService.getContent(type, prop);`  I changed it to `const content = modalService.getContent('my_element1', prop);`.